# Three.js GLSL shader couldn't compile

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

I'm getting a compile error: `THREE.WebGLShader: Shader couldn't compile.`

I tried to insert some shaders grabbed from shaderfrog.com but they don't seem to compile.

I've used an example file and added my new vertex shader and fragment shader in to the dom.

```js
<script id="vertexShader_new" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  . . .
</script>
```

```js
material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader_new').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader_new').textContent
});
```

I've changed the id's back to `vertexShader` and `fragmentShader` in the demo to show that the rest of the code is working with a simpler shader.

[image: Edit practical-kepler-3pdps]

What's wrong with the shader?
Link with the shader: [Molten Noise shader](https://shaderfrog.com/app/view/292)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in you code:

- You have to use `RawShaderMaterial` instead of `ShaderMaterial`. Otherwise it's wrong to define attributes like `position` or `normal` since they are part of the set of *Built-in attributes and uniforms*, see [docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/ShaderMaterial).
- You have to define all uniforms in your shader definition, not just two of it. Otherwise the uniforms have undefined values which produces a wrong output. So the correct uniforms definition looks like so (notice that it's not necessary to define a `type` property anymore).

  ```
  uniforms = {
      color1: { value: new THREE.Color( 0xff0000 ) },
      color2: { value: new THREE.Color( 0x00ff00 ) },
      color3: { value: new THREE.Color( 0x0000ff ) },
      iterations: { value: 1 },
      permutations: { value: 10 },
      brightness: { value: 1 },
      time: { value: 1 },
      speed: { value: 0.02 },
      uvScale: { value: new THREE.Vector2(1, 1) }
  };
  ```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qb6u8vjp/5/

`three.js R105`